# How to remove elements from a list under some conditions?

Tags: python, binary-search

I want to implement Binary Search algorithm in python considering the following list:

```
Fibonacci_Seq = [1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89]
```

So, I wrote a function to do the calculation but when I came down to this block of code, I didn't know what to do:

```
min = Fibonacci_Seq[0] #is 1
max = Fibonacci_Seq[-1] #is 89
goal = Fibonacci_Seq[4] #Equals to 5
guess = (min+max)//2  #Equals to 45
if guess > goal: #Is true
            (guess-1)//2 #Equals to 22
            del Fibonacci_Seq[the elements that are less than 22]
```

Instead of "The elements that are less than 22", what can I write to eliminate the the numbers less than 22 since putting basic '<=>' signs don't work?

Comment: try not to use `min` and `max` as variables, they are [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).

Answer (score 1):

Do a modified Binary Search to find the index of that first element which is greater than or equal to 22 and then just slice the existing list.

In your case the index is `8` such that `Fibonacci_Seq[8]=34` and then just slice your list as `Fibonacci_Seq=Fibonacci_Seq[8:]`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use numpy:

```
import numpy as np
Fibonacci_Seq = np.array([1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89])
where = Fibonacci_Seq<22
Fibonacci_Seq = Fibonacci_Seq[where]
```